# How to fix PHP sprintf behavior?

Tags: php, printf

**Context**

- PHP
- XAMPP

**Why does this not print anything?**

```
$a=sprintf('<s');
echo $a;
```

Comment: According to http://codepad.org/9qjZL2bf this prints <s like it's supposed to do... The problem is somewhere else ;)

Comment: Tested with PHP5.3.something on Ubuntu 11.4. Nothing curious, works fine and as expected.

Comment: I agree. I just dont understand where. The code above is the only code im running. Im using XAMPP. Would that change anything?

Comment: I think its your browser. Try viewing source.

Comment: Yes..., HTML-/XML-Tags starts with `<`. Have a look at the source of this "page".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you outputting into a browser? The `<a` could be interpreted as the start of a tag (which happens to be incomplete/unclosed) and therefore hidden. If this is the case, check the page's source. Never trust the main browser window when debugging script output, as it'll hide things from you by design.

Comment: Add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` somewhere at the beginning. Then nothing is hidden by the browser engine and everything looks like on the command line :)

Comment: true enough. I find it easier to just hit ctrl-U in FF

Comment: In the end I used sprintf('&lt;s') to get the desired output.

Comment: @twerd: which means you were outputting to a browser, and the browser was interpreting those two characters as a partial tag.

Answer (score 3):

It works fine on my Linux machine.

```
$ php <<< '<?php $a=sprintf("<s"); echo $a; ?>'
<s
```

You might be getting bitten by buffering. Try adding a newline to your printout, or use `var_dump()`.

```
echo "$a\n";
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 2):

It does print <s

```
<swesley@ubuntu:~$ cat blah.php


<?php
$a=sprintf('<s');
echo $a;
?>



wesley@ubuntu:~$ php blah.php

<s

wesley@ubuntu:~$
```

My guess is that your running this in a browser and that interprets it as the start of a html tag.

Comment: Thanks!! Thats exactly what happened

Answer (score 0):

If you view source on your rendered html you will see that it is in fact there.
you have to escape the html character "<" otherwise your browser will try to render it.

```
$a=sprintf('&lt;s');
echo $a;
```

[Reference](http://www.html-reference.com/Escape.asp)

Comment: Better to use `echo htmlspecialchars($a);`